# triggers. if they work in the same project and live in the city as another employee

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm still very new to sql, and am now trying to learn how to make triggers. I want to make a trigger when inserting it into the employee's table. If the new employee works on the same project and lives in the same city as someone, throw an error, and don't insert. otherwise, insert it into the table.

"employees"

| employeeid | name | city | projectid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jeff | detroit | 1 |
| 2 | larry | LA | 1 |
| 3 | Linda | Orlando | 1 |
| 4 | tom | Dalas | 2 |

and lets say we try to insert

```
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (5, 'ward', LA, 1);
```

This would of course fail as he would be working on project 1 and lives in LA, which larry already does.  so this would throw an error.
I was trying to use duplicate_info to exception to do this but always seems to still insert.  Any guidance on how to write triggers would be helpful.

```
REATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER same_city
BEFORE INSERT
ON employee
DECLARE
    duplicate_info EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (duplicate_info, -00001);
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' *** Inserting');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN duplicate_info THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (
    num=> -10000,
    msg=> 'Duplicate ');
END no_same_zip;
```

Comment: You could have a basic unique constraint instead.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: I'm using oracle

Comment: Try removing `WHEN duplicate_info THEN` and most of the code before it and using `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM employee WHERE name = NEW.name and city = NEW.city) THEN` instead.

Comment: I get an error when using  " EXISTS".  It says "function or pseudo-column 'EXISTS' may be used inside a SQL statement only" @bohemian

Answer (score 0):

Use `:new` to get the inserting values and use them to find existing row count and raise exception if it finds one:

```sql
create or replace trigger same_city
before insert on employee
for each row
begin
  if (select count(*)
    from employee
    where projectId = :new.projectId
    and city = :new.city) > 0
  then 
    raise_application_error(-10000, 'Duplicate');
  end if;
end;
```

Note that `for each row` is required to have access to `:new`.